# Images are "stuck" and visible all the time on the screen

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Something really weird is happening. Sometimes images "freeze" and show up all the time on top of everything. This time it was an image from the finder preview, I suspect that it's always photos from finder but I can not confirm that 100%.

I recorded a video of my screen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ9dg.jpg

[image]

Any idea what causes this? Only a restart resolves the issue for me for some days, then it happens seemingly randomly again.

Thanks!:)